# How does the all function work in R using two expressions?

Tags: r

I have an issue with the all function in R.

let `a` and `b` two vectors:

```
a <- c(Inf,0)

b <- c(1,0)
```

When I try to evaluate the expression `all(a==b)` the function returns `FALSE`, is OK, if it is evaluated the expression `all(a==Inf)` the function returns `FALSE`, so far all is working OK, but if I try to evaluate the expression `all((a==b) | (a==Inf))` the function returns `TRUE`.

Could someone explain me why?

Comment: I guess I don't know what else you would expect from this?  In the future providing your expected output and the reasoning behind the output you expect can not only help get better answers but also help you get answers that show you how to do what you're actually expecting.  In this case I'm guessing maybe you wanted something like `all(a==b) | all(a==Inf)` but it's hard to tell since there isn't any expected output provided.

Comment: I had to convert r code to java code and for this reason i needed to know what exactly the all function did in this expression, I didn't know about how column wise works in r.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OR` is done column wise:

```r
a <- c(Inf,0)
b <- c(1,0)

(a==b) 
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE
(a==Inf)
#> [1] TRUE   FALSE
(a==Inf)|(a==b) 
#> [1] TRUE   TRUE
```

In each column there's a `TRUE` so each column is `TRUE`

Answer (score 2):

When you type `help("|")`, you will see that `|` is element-wise `OR`.

---

In this case, given

```
> (a == b)
[1] FALSE  TRUE

> (a == Inf)
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

the expression `(a == b) | (a == Inf)` is equivalent to

```
c(FALSE, TRUE) | c(TRUE, FALSE)
```

and the resultant logic array is `c(TRUE, TRUE)`, which gives you `TRUE` when you apply `all` over it.